# PInvoke and double*

Tags: c#, .net, interop, pinvoke

I apologize if this is a duplicate. I am writing a class that needs to interact with an old c++ unmanaged dll. There is one method that I am having a hard time mapping to managed code:

```
long DoSomething(int id, double* points, long numberOfPoints, bool useShaping)
```

I have been thus far unable to map that to an extern method that does not throw a stack unbalanced exception. The problem is with the double pointer. What would the method signature look for in managed code? Here's what I've tried that does not work as an example.

```
[DllImport("Something.Dll", EntryPoint = "DoSomething")]
public static extern long DoSomething(int id, double[] points, long numberOfPoints, bool useShaping)
```

Comment: Do you need to consume the double that points points to?

Comment: This is PInvoke, not COM interop...

Comment: First of all you need to figure out the calling convention. Is it `stdcall` or `cdecl`? If you mix those up, the call itself will work, but on .net 4 you'll get an imbalanced stack exception.

Comment: I do need to consume the points parameter in some situations. Oddly enough, the parameter serves as both input and output. A null value indicates that the method should return the number of points it would put into the array. A non-null value populates the array with the number of points indicated by the number of points parameter and in this case the method returns 1/0 for success/failure.

Comment: have you tried using an IntPtr in the dllimport signature and marshalling the array back and forth yourself with the Marshal class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are likely two problems -

1. This most likely needs to specify the calling convention.
2. "long" in C++ maps to "int" in C#

Try the following:

```
[DllImport("Something.Dll", EntryPoint = "DoSomething", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int DoSomething(int id, double[] points, int numberOfPoints, bool useShaping);
```

Comment: The calling convention seemed to be the lynch pin here. In my case, I needed to set it to StdCall. Thanks everybody for the quick responses. I obviously have little experience with pinvoke.